# How to use "jQuery.when" inside a jQuery ajax success callback?

Tags: jquery

How to use `jQuery.when(..).done()` inside an Ajax success callback?

**Javascript**

```
button = function () {
    doPost('sucess.php',
        'first=' + first,
        function (response) {
            $.when($.ajax("sucess.php")).done(function (a1) { 
                // Stop the  button function execution 
            });
        }
    );
}
doPost = function (url, data, success, complete, options) {
    var defaults = {
        url:url,
        data:data,
        success:success,
        complete:complete,
        type:'POST',
        processData:false
    };
    if (options) {
        for (var i in options) {
            defaults[i] = options[i];
        }
    }
    $.ajax(defaults);
}
```

Above code doesn't works for some reasons.
Please see that anything went wrong with  my `$.when(..).done()` statement.

Comment: I appreciate that English may not be your first language, but you need to ask a question.

Comment: Jusnit, take a look at my edited answer and see if it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery.when anywhere; however, you have to know how to apply it.

Go here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
 function(response) {
     $.when($.ajax("sucess.php").then( function ()  { 
         // code to stop the  button function execution 
     })
 }
```

Comment: I have used $.when($.ajax("sucess.php").done(function(a1){  } );   but get an error '$.when is not a function' , then I used jquery nonConflict still error goes on .How can I solve this problem

Comment: You had forgotten to close the parenthesis after success.php. Try $.when($.ajax("success.php")).done( function () {} ). Is a1 something coming from success.php?

Answer (score 1):

I see in your response to zequinha-bsb that you get the following error:

```
'$.when is not a function'
```

Which version of jQuery are you using? It might be good to keep in mind that $.when is not introduced before jQuery 1.5.

Comment: It's `jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6`.